# Find the volume of the solid using integral methods

Tags: integration, rotations, volume

Find the volume of the solid generated by rotating the following area around the y-axis.

The area will be bounded by $y=x^4$, $x=1$ and $y=0$.

What method is the easiest for this? I'm assuming shell method where the radius is $x$ and the height is $x^4$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: In this case Shells is simpler than Slicing. You are well on your way to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the formula:

$\pi \int_0^1 dy  R_1^2(y) - \pi \int_0^1 dy  R_2^2(y)$

$R_1(y)$ is the $x=1$ bound.

$R_2(y)$ is the $y=x^4$ bound, which is more conveniently expressed as $x=y^{1/4}$.

This method integrates disks with radius $R(y)$.

You would then write:

$\pi \int_0^1 dy - \pi \int_0^1 dy  (y^{1/4})^2$

$= \pi - \frac{2\pi}{3} $

$=\frac{\pi}{3}$